# Force MS Remoteapp to save files to client's System

Tags: remoteapp

I'm using an older software with a dbase database. I'd like to deploy it as a remoteapp, and from my testing this seems quite possible.

Update: 
This application would be accessed over the internet and not directly on the same network.
Additionally the users would be using a variety of devices.

My question is this:

This application generates excel and csv files, how can I force remote app to save these files to the clients machine and not save anything generated (or through a save dialog) to the server?

Comment: is it possible to map a drive to \\tsclient\c\$$$  ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the client machine folders, and then write to those. Given the application vintage you may need to wrap it in a batch file that sets up the mapped drives.

Alternately, create persistent mappings in a regular RDP session. It should also be possible to create mappings to the \tsclient\? virtual folders created in the session during a script. This way, an application that needs to access mapped drives can reach the folders on the client machine.

Comment: Additional Information: This application would be accessed over the internet and not directly on the same network.  I've never had any success mapping drives to a remote network.